# Nest ElasticSearch cannot convert Lambda expression

Tags: nest

The following VB code is intended to add an alias index to a nest elastic search but the final line receives an error -

> "lambda expression cannot be converted to NEST.IAliasRequest because Nest.IAliasRequest is not a delegate type"

```
    Dim client = ConnectToSearch()

    Dim Person = New Person With {.Id=  Id, .Description = Description, .Tags = Tags}

    client.Alias(Sub(a) a.Add(Function(add) add.Index("Person").Alias("Account1")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.[Alias](Function(descriptor) descriptor.Add(Function(a) a.Index("Person").[Alias]("Account1")))
```

*UPDATE*

Maybe this one will help you create alias with filter.

```
client.[Alias](Function([alias]) [alias].Add(Function(a) a.Index(indexName).[Alias]("alias").Filter(Of Person)(Function(f) f.Term("relationships.staffID", staffID))))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added a filter but am now receiving this error:

Type parameter 'T' for 'Public Function Filter(Of T As Class)(filterSelector As System.Func(Of Nest.FilterDescriptor(Of T), Nest.FilterContainer)) As Nest.AliasAddDescriptor' cannot be inferred.

The code is now:
client.[Alias](Function(descriptor) descriptor.Add(Function(a) a.Index(Index).[Alias](Index & " _" & AccountId).[Routing](AccountId).[Filter](Function(f) f.Term("relationships.staffID", staffID))))


sorry haven't got to grips with this yet. Can you spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: Thanks, think I understand this better now.

Comment: From VB you might have a better experience using the object initializer syntax e.g `New AliasRequest With { .`